# Java - NullPointerException while simply reading a file and returning an int

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, filereader

I am trying to read a file and figure out how many times a `String` occurs in that file. Depending on how many times, it will display a different dialogue to the player (it's a game). Here is my code

```
/**
 * Selects which dialogue to send depending on how many times the player has been jailed
 * @return The dialogue ID
 */
public static int selectChat() {
    System.err.println("Got to selectChar()");
    FileUtil.stringOccurrences(c.playerName, // NULLPOINTER HAPPENS HERE
        "./data/restrictions/TimesJailed.txt");

    if (FileUtil.stringCount == 1)
        return 495;
    if (FileUtil.stringCount == 2)
        return 496;
    if (FileUtil.stringCount >= 3) {
        return 497;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And then this is the actual file reading method

```
public static int stringCount;

/**
 * @param string
 * @param filePath
 * @return How many occurrences of the string there are in the file
 */
public static int stringOccurrences(String string, String filePath) {
    int count = 0;

    try {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;

        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (strLine.contains(string))
                count++;
        }

        in.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) { // Catch exception if any
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    System.err.println(count);
    stringCount = count;
    return count;
}
```

Here is all I do with c

```
Client c;

public Jail(Client c) {
    this.c = c;
}
```

Could someone please help me work out the problem.

Comment: Try printing out whether or not c.playerName is null (System.out.println(c.playerName == null)) right before doing FileUtil.stringOccurences(..)

Comment: I figured it out, but I can't show you why because I don't have enough to answer my own question. Or I have to wait another 7 hours... Thank you for the help !

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that `c` in `c.playerName` is null.

Also depending on what `FileUtil` you use, that might cause a `NullPointerException` as well, when `playerName` is null.

Answer (score 0):

Your `stringOccurrences` method cannot throw an NPE as far as I can tell -- it makes no dereferences outside the `try`/`catch` block.

Where do you assign a value to `c`?  If it is null, then your attempt to read `c.playerName` will produce a `NullPointerException`.  To see for sure if this is happening, change your code to:

```
String myPlayerName = c.playerName; //now does NPE happen here ...
FileUtil.stringOccurrences(myPlayerName, // or here?
        "./data/restrictions/TimesJailed.txt");
```

Comment: It happens at String myPlayerName

Comment: So then `c` must be `null`.  With your added info, this means that the caller of `Jail(Client c)` is passing in `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Please write your constructor as below;

```
   Client c;

  public Jail(Client c) {
     if(c == null) {
         c = new Client();
     }
  }
```